# Problema con consulta select MAX en MySql

Tags: mysql

tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT 
    h.cod_hoja,p.nombre, 
    p.universidad, 
    d.nombre_diagnostico, 
    h.hojaEvolucion, 
    h.planEvolucion,
    h.fecha_consulta,
    h.hora_consulta 
FROM hoja_evolucion as h 
    JOIN paciente_hoja as ph on ph.cod_hojaFK = h.cod_hoja 
    JOIN pacientes as p on p.cedula= ph.cedulaFK 
    JOIN citas as c ON c.cedulaFK = p.cedula 
    JOIN diagnostico as d ON c.cod_diagnosticoFK = d.cod_diagnostico 
WHERE h.cod_hoja = (select MAX(cod_hoja) from hoja_evolucion)
```

Necesito que en teoria me devuelva los datos seleccionados del ultimo registro insertado en hoja_evolucion. Perro me esta devolviendo dos registros el mismo cod_hoja, lo cual no se porque pasa, ya que cod_hoja es la llave primaria, por lo cual no se puede repetir.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque está teniendo dos filas en `diagnostico`, si observas los resultados. Si te interesa una sola fila puedes ponerle un `LIMIT 1`  al final, pero mira la columna `nombre_diagnostico` y decide si es en realidad lo que quieres.

Comment: @A.Cedano aparte dle `LIMIT 1` no le serviría hacer un `ORDER BY cod_hoja DESC LIMIT 1` para no solo obtener uno sino además el mas reciente?

Comment: @shadow es posible, o bien cambiar el `WHERE` por esto: `ORDER BY h.cod_hoja DESC LIMIT 1` ... no sé si funcione. De todos modos la divergencia de datos en `nombre_diagnostico` es (o puede ser) inquietante... ¿a cuál de los dos quitamos de en medio? ¿da igual uno u otro? ¿por qué hace `JOIN` dos veces en esa tabla?

Comment: @A.Cedano cambiar el WHERE por esto: ORDER BY h.cod_hoja DESC LIMIT 1 me funcionó muy bien, pero no entiendo porque con mi consulta original devuelve dos cod_hoja iguales, si se supone que es un PK

Comment: @Oscar Alberto Rodríguez es cierto es una PK pero fíjate en nombre_diagnostico pues está asignada a diagnósticos distintos

Comment: Oscar, efectivamente si debe haber una sola fila, bastaría con `ORDER BY h.cod_hoja DESC LIMIT 1`, pero debes revisar la forma en que se están introduciendo los datos y muy probablemente deberías agregar algunas restricciones `UNIQUE` en algunas tablas, si quieres evitar que se inserten duplicados. Lo que se puede deducir viendo los resultados es que *habría un paciente con dos citas y con dos diagnósticos distintos*, lo cual no es descabellado, un paciente puede estar siendo visto por dos médicos porque tiene dos enfermedades diferentes...

Answer (score 0):

select cod_hoja from hoja_evolucion WHERE cod_hoja = 23;

Para saber que solo hay un registro, sí esto te trae un solo registro deberías de ver tu consulta porque debe tener algo malo.

- corrección: el max funciona bien lo que pasa es que tienes un puente en el join seguro en una cita hay uno o varios diagnostico si vez la imagen que pones no se repite la fila pues en nombre diagnostico son distinto tienes diagnostico 1 y diagnostico 2. y eso es correcto.

Comment: Si te fijas en la tabla si hay razón de ser que le muestre dos fijas con el mismo id

Comment: si arriba corregí mi intervención ya lo vi bien el max funciona pero el tiene un puente de 1 a muchos por eso le trae dos registro y si la cita tuviera x cantidad le traería esa x cantidad de registro